# What is the purpose of oauth-token of Ruby on Rails gem omniauth-facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, omniauth, facebook-login

I'm using `has_secure_password` and `bcrypt` for authentication, but not `deivse`.  I basically refer [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) and pass in all the data such as `provider/uid/info.name/credentials.token`. Since my User model validates `password`, so I try to pass in the `oauth-token` as `password` so I can put this user in my db. My question is, is there any security risk for treating `oauth-token` as password? What is the original purpose for `oauth-token`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even really know where to start... It's unclear if you are trying to implement FB Connect, and doing it wrong or trying to implement user authentication, and doing it wrong by using OAuth related stuff.

OAuth tokens are used to authenticate yourself against a third party, in order to access their API for example. So in case of Facebook Connect you would have the user authorize themselves and then get an OAuth token for them, so you can access the third party in their behalf. I suggest reading up on OAuth resources for this.

Either way using an OAuth token for whatever password is wrong. OAuth tokens are not permanent, they expire and they can be revoked and regenerated. Meaning in your case the password would change in all of those cases. If you are just implementing OAuth connect, you don't need any kind of passwords for the user at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying to implement FB connect(social login) with the gem `omniauth-facebook`, and since my User model validates on password, if any user use social login without a password will fail, so I try to use the oauth-token generated by moniauth as a password(the password will not be plain text since I use bcrypt for authentiaction).     It works fine now and I'm just wondering if there is any unknown security issue by doing so. Thanks for your reply

Comment: If you are just filling in the password so your User model would be valid, I would suggest just generating a random password instead of using a token hash. Something like SecureRandom.hex(8) should be fine (it generates a 16 chars long random hex string).